# What is the best way to NOT fetch a byte[] column when getting a persistent entity?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, hql

The table has multiple properties which we want to always be fetched. But it also has one property which is very large. When getting the information to display a list of items to the user the request will be significantly slower if the large property is fetched and it's not even used.

So far I've only managed to make it work by wrapping that byte[] in a separate Object and referencing it with a `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` which seems like poor design. `@Lob` `@Basic` and `@OneToOne` don't seem to work and I would rather not have that property in a separate Object anyway.

Comment: Probably not the way to go: but we made that blob not part of the entity, and then used a separate repository with which we manually connected to the database from which we then read that blob as an `Inputstream`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have tried annotating the byte[] array with 
`@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`.  When using the `@Basic` annotation and lazy fetching additional hibernate options must be set.  See the Hibernate Documentation - [Performing Enhancement Section](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement-enhancement)

Specifically, the `hibernate.enhancer.enableLazyInitialization` property must be set to true.  By default it is not enabled.

Comment: I tried using the plugin and added the optinal = false property as well. Still didn't work. I guess it probably can be made to work but  using some bytecode enhancement plugin seems like the worst solution to me.

Comment: Using the bytecode enhancement seems like the cleanest solution to me.  Otherwise I think you will be stuck with implementing a similar proxy mechanism that the bytecode enhancer creates for you, or jumping through hoops like @Lino suggested.  Any reasons why you have an aversion to it?